# VMWare API / Java - Separating folders from Datastores

Tags: java, directory, vmware, datastore

I am using vim (the Java API for VMWare, not vim25 a later version) to return a list of datastores using:

```
ManagedObjectReference[] datastores = (ManagedObjectReference[])cb.getServiceUtil().getDynamicProperty(dcmor, "datastore");
```

This returns the complete set of Datastores, but mixed in with them are the folders. 
Using DatastoreSummary and DatastoreInfo show no variations between the two.

Even

```
for (int j = 0; j < datastores.length; j++) {
    System.out.println(datastores[j].getType());
}
```

shows the Type of the folders as Datastore.

Is there any element that can be used to filter out those pesky folders??

Comment: What does your problem have to do with Vim?

Comment: I'm not sure what "vim" means in this context but it's not what the tag signifies which is the vim editor and it's associated scripting language.

Comment: Sorry, wrong Vim tag! vim is the vmware API for Java.